# Not sure what this line of code means in C

Tags: c

Stumbled across this particular line of code and am having some trouble understanding it:

```
a = ((((z * y) + 31) & ~31) / 8) * abs(x);
```

`a`, `z`, `y`, and `x` all are of type `int`.

I understand that `~` has the effect of flipping all the `1`'s and `0`'s, in this case, doesn't `31` become `0`? How does the `&` come into play in this line? Isn't it used for logical statements rather than equations like this?

Comment: Why do you think only the lowest bits will be flipped, and not the higher, 0-bits too?

Comment: `&` is bitwise "and". `&&` is short-circuit logical "and". See any decent C reference for more information.

Comment: Split the line up in it parts, with temporary variables. Then run through that code in a debugger, stepping line by line. That will make it very easy to see what going on.

Comment: As an interesting point the behavior of the line is such that it produces `(z*y)/32.0` rounded up to the next integer multiplied by `4 * abs(x)` for `z * y >= 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's step through the code using a simple example. Let's set `x = y = z = 10;` for the example. Your single line can be split up into several parts:

```
temp1 = z * y;
temp2 = temp1 + 31;
temp3 = temp2 & ~31;
temp4 = temp3 / 8;
a = temp4 * abs(x);
```

Here, `temp1`-`temp4` are also of type `int`. Using the above code and the example values, `temp1` and `temp2` are straightforward to calculate:

```
temp1 = 10 * 10 = 100
temp2 = 100 + 31 = 131
```

To get `temp3`, we need to know the binary representation of `temp2`, which in this case is `10000011`. As such, we get:

```
  10000011
& 11100000
----------
  10000000 = 128 in decimal
```

So `temp3 = 128`. From here, `temp4` and `a` are trivial:

```
temp4 = 128 / 8 = 16
a = 16 * 10 = 160
```

For future reference, when you are confused what a line of code does, first split it up like I've done above, then use a debugger (like gdb) to step through the code. That will help make the code clear.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the confusion stems from the fact that you've incorrectly evaluated `~31` in your head.
For the simple case of 8-bit numbers 31 is actually `00011111` and therefore `~31` = `11100000` Not `00000000`. To answer your question about the `&` operator, it's a bitwise AND operator, just as `~` is a bitwise NOT operator; therefore, `((z * y) + 31) & ~31` performs the bitwise AND operation on the result of `(z * y) + 31` and `~31`